# Inferring partial type parameter list to generic value parameter

Tags: scala, typeclass

Why is it that Scala can't infer like so?

```
def notInfering[A,B,C](aa: A=>Boolean, bbcc: Tuple2[B,C]) = bbcc
notInfering[Int]((_ > 3), ("string", 123))
```

Compiler angrily says I need to specify type arguments B and C.

These work, but they're not ideal:

```
notInfering[Int,String,Int]((_ > 2), ("string", 123))
notInfering(((a: Int) => a > 2), ("string", 123))
```

In theory, shouldn't Scala be able to infer the last two parameters?  Can this be done or expressed in another way?  If not, would this be a good feature for Scala to be able to infer a partial type parameter list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, a language could implement the described functionality.  It's just that Scala currently doesn't.

First of all, what you're describing simply isn't part of the Scala syntax.  When specifying type arguments, it's an all-or-nothing syntax.  You either need all of the type arguments, or let the compiler infer them.

Second of all, remember that type inference is not perfect.  There are plenty of situations in which a type argument can be inferred by hand, but the compiler cannot figure it out.  The Scala compiler is quite impressive at type disambiguation and deduction, but it's not magic!

Finally, this can be expressed using Scala with an intermediate closure class (can be an anonymous class) that holds the first type parameter:

```
object Foo {
    def inferring[A](aa: A => Boolean) = new {
        def apply[B, C](bbcc: (B, C)) = bbcc
    }
}
```

And then you can do:

```
Foo.inferring[Int](_ > 3)("string" -> 123)
```

As desired.